# How i can call my plugin use shortcode Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin file. It has html and php code. I would like to call it with shortcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can do all stuff into

```
 function myshort( $atts ) {

//add your html php code here

    add_shortcode( 'my_short', 'myshort' );
```

then use shortocde [my_short] in your pages